# How to get social media meta tags into head for blog-pages in WordPress instead of body

Tags: wordpress, meta

I have a website on WordPress (Im still new to WordPress) and in it I created a Blog-Page. I made the blog page with custom PHP code however, now I wanna add some custom `<meta>` tags for social media sharing such as Facebook or Twitter etc.

However in my document it only has the body and an WordPress anchor

```
/* 
* Template Name: news-article 
* Template Post Type: page 
*/ 
get_header();
```

so if i put it on the blog-page then it wont work because it is only the body and `<meta>` don't work in body. If i go to the header then it is general header function that will be on every page on the WordPress website.

So Do I put it in the general Header and just like have a conditional statement so it doesn't run on every page other than the blog pages, or is there a way in WordPress to do this?
Thank you in advance

> EDIT

```
<!-- for blog pages -->
    <?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $rs_news_rows['nsubheading'] . '">
        <meta property="og:title" content="' . $rs_news_rows['nheadline'] .'">
        <meta property="og:description" content="'. $rs_news_rows['nsubheading'].'">'
 }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use this PHP code in your template

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everyting else
}
```

Or simply

```
if ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
}
```

Comment: do i add this to the header page or the blog-page im working on ?

Comment: Can add to the header page.

Comment: I have added an edit to show what i did. i added that to the header and it shows up the `<!-- for blog pages -->` but not actual meta tags show up